# pip3.4: command not found

Tags: raspbian, pip

I am trying to install oxygen but getting this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/git/toxcore $ sudo pip3.4 install toxygen
sudo: pip3.4: command not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the output of which pip. Usually you should get the installer path like /usr/bin/pip. If it says no pip3.4 it means its not there on your system.

if you want to see the details of pip say is it python 2.7 or 3.4 compatible check the version of pip using /usr/bin/pip -V It would say something like

pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python2.7)